# jQuery loop each radio button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very simple , this st**id tinny things will kill me.

I trying loop each radio button.

```
$('#recover input:radio:checked').each(function() {
  alert("checked");
});
```

OR

```
 function Checkform() {
    var result = true;
    $('#recover input[type=radio]').each(function() {
        var checked = $(this).find('input:radio:checked');
        if (checked.length == 0) {
            result = false;
            alert ("check");
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

OR

```
 $('#recover input[type=radio]').each(function(){
 if($(this).attr('checked')){
    alert ("check");
  }
});
```

HTML :

```
<div id="recover">
  <input type="radio" name="s">
  <input type="radio" name="s">
  <input type="radio" name="s">
</div>
```

tryed also :

```
<div id="recover">
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="s">
  <input type="radio" name="s">
  <input type="radio" name="s">
</form>
</div>
```

And:

```
<div id="recover">
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="s" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="s" value="2">
  <input type="radio" name="s" value="2">
</form>
</div>
```

And more combination of HTML .

And tryed more like 5 other examples of jQuery / Javascript, **none** working and i dont know why .

Any help please , thanks allot.

Comment: What's the goal ? BTW, "#recovery" won't work if the id is "recover".

Comment: `recover` and `recovery` :P..hope you got it

Comment: I need to loop each radio button O.o, the ID is not recovery its recover maybe spelling mistake in StackOverFlaw question i will fix it.

Comment: $('#recovery input[type=radio]').each(function(){ if($(this).attr('checked')){alert ("check");}}); - This code is right. See the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/saranyaciet/AmEZ4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$(this).prop('checked')` instead of `$(this).attr('checked')`

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/6Yed6/)

---

## [Attributes vs. Properties](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)

> ...
>
> Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the **checked
>   attribute** is that it does not correspond to the **checked property**. The
>   attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and
>   should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The
>   checked attribute value does not change with the state of the
>   checkbox, while the checked property does. **Therefore, the
>   cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is
>   to use the property**:
>
> ```
> if ( elem.checked )
> if ( $( elem ).prop( "checked" ) )
> if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) )
> ```
>
> The same is true for other dynamic attributes, such as **selected** and
>   **value**.

Comment: both are same i guess

Comment: I tryed everything nothing work , and i dont get any error's , very weird.

Comment: @asdasdasda It does work. See the fiddle in my updated answer.

Comment: I know , it's should work i dont understand why it's not working on me, other function's , jQuery , working perfect.

Comment: Well of course it won't do anything. On the `ready` event you haven't checked any `radio` button yet, why would it alert anything with the current code? See my fiddle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38389/discussion-between-itay-and-asdasd-asda)

Answer (score 1):

TRy this Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/X6QhN/

```
function doCheck(){
   $('#recover input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function() {
  alert("checked");
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **[prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**
because it gives true or false

and **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

gives property name like checked or not so cant use in condition

```
   $('#recovery input[type=radio]').each(function(){
     if($(this).prop('checked')){
        alert ("check");
      }
    });
```

reference [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: which jquery vesrion you use @asdasdasda

Comment: /js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You can access the checked property directly from the dom reference

```
$('#recover input[type=radio]').each(function () {
    if (this.checked) { // or $(this).is(':checked')
        alert("check");
    }
});
```

If you want to process only checked items then use the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector

```
$('#recover input[type=radio]:checked').each(function () {
    alert("check");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pwqrx/)

Comment: I tryed this too and its not working , i check if my div id is the same like 100 times and its the same i dont understand why not working..

Comment: @asdasdasda see the attached fiddle

Comment: Yea i understand , no one calling this code it's on document.ready

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#recover > radio').each(function(){
     if($(this).prop('checked')){
        alert ("checked");
      }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This 
`

```
               jQuery(function ()
               {
        if (jQuery('#recover input[name="s"]').is(':checked'))
        {
               alert("Checked");            }
        else
        {

             alert("Please select an Record");
          }
    });`
```